# How to import extern const from iOS (or Mac) into Delphi

Tags: objective-c, delphi, delphi-xe

I'm working on conversion of whole libraries of iOS into Delphi.

I can convert all functions, records etc..

But when I'm importing CoreMIDI there are `CFStringRef` constants declared as:

```
extern const CFStringRef    kMIDIPropertyName;
```

and many others that I need to import in order to use some of the functions.

I was looking at the internet and I didn't found any straight way how to do it.

Question is - isn't there some way, for example to load the DLL and get list of the parameters and somehow read the value manually?

I don't care about the effort, but I need it working. And it must work under iOS.

Thanks for any tip of suggestion.

Comment: You've tried dlsym I presume?

Comment: I tried this code:
 `libAudioToolbox = '/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox';
MPModule := dlopen(MarshaledAString(libAudioToolbox), RTLD_LAZY); `

but the MPModule is at the iPhone 0

Comment: Don't you need to link statically on iOS?

Comment: You totally right. I just got at the other answer that I can use RTLD_DEFAULT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import symbols on iOS by using `dlsym`. Since dynamic link is not allowed on iOS you do not call `dlopen` first. Pass 
`RTLD_DEFAULT` as the module handle when you call `dlsym`. Like this

```
Symbol := dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, SymbolName);
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes this is working .. when I call dlsym with RTLD_DEFAULT I get the pointer on the value.